# Empty value "- Select -" does not appear for select fields with states requirement

Tags: 7, forms

When I create a standard select box using the Drupal 7 form API, the first value (also the one selected on a fresh 'blank form') is `<option selected="selected" value="">- Select -</option>`. This value is not specified in the form definition and I am doing no form altering. (This is fine)

However, when I create a second select box that depends on the first using `#states`, it does not have any such default value. For complex forms with multiple dependencies this inconsistency is a problem.

An example form definition is as follows:

```
function sb_quickquote_test_form($form, &$form_state, $post=array()) {

  $fields['first_select'] = array(
    '#type'             => 'select',
    '#title'            => 'First select box',
    '#options'          => Array('First', 'Second', 'Third'),
    '#required'         => TRUE,
  );

  $fields['dependent_delect'] = array(
    '#type'             => 'select',
    '#title'            => 'Dependent select box',
    '#options'          => Array('Something', 'Another thing', 'Something else', 'Final thing'),
    '#states'           => Array(
      'visible' => Array('select[name=first_select]' => array('value' => '2')),
      'required' => Array('select[name=first_select]' => array('value' => '2')),
    ),
  );

  $fields['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );
  return $fields;
}
```

In this simple example, we have 2 select boxes and a submit button. The two select boxes are displayed as:

```
 ______________      ________________
| - Select - |v|    | Something    |v|
`--------------'    `----------------'
| - Select -   |    | Something      | <- no empty option
| First        |    | Another thing  |
| Second       |    | Something else |
| Third        |    | Final thing    |
 --------------      ----------------
```

(Because of the `#states` setting, the second select box only appears when the first select box has "Third" selected)

This inconsistency is causing problems in a situation where we are generating complex dynamic forms with inter-dependant fields.

Does anyone have any idea why the fields are being given inconsistent options and what the best approach is to work around the problem?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To force the "empty option", assign it with something like:

```
"#empty_option"=>t('- Select -'),
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't have Drupal set up anywhere to check this so I'll have to take your word for it and keep an eye on the votes from others!

Comment: This fix also works for Drupal 8

Answer (score 3):

you need change this:

```
 'visible' => Array('select[name=first_select]' => array('value' => '2')),
 'required' => Array('select[name=first_select]' => array('value' => '2')),
```

select to ：input

the correct code is :

```
 'visible' => Array(':input[name="first_select"]' => array('value' => '2')),
 'required' => Array(':input[name="first_select"]' => array('value' => '2')),
```

Answer (score 2):

To extend doterobcn answer you can also set the empty value (the key) of your empty option.

In Drupal 8:

```
$form['country'] = [
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#multiple' => FALSE,
  '#title' => t('Country:'),
  '#required' => FALSE,
  '#options' => $countries,
  '#default_value' => 'FR',
  '#empty_option' => t('- None -'),
  '#empty_value' => '_none',
];
```

Which will give :

```
<option value="_none">- None -</option>
```